# Unmarshal into pointer vs value receiver feilds

Tags: go

I'm learning Golang recently. I know pointer and value receivers how it works generally.

When Unmarshal JSON string like follow 2 examples, I feel that first one (pointer receiver) more efficient way to use memory. But I have seen lots of examples and articles not uses this way. Is there any reason for this? And what are use cases for them?

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Outer struct {
    ID           int          `json:"id"`
    PointerValue *string      `json:"pointer_str"`
    Inner        *Inner `json:"inner"`
}
type Inner struct {
    Value string `json:"value"`
}

func main() {
    testJson := `{
            "id": 1,
            "pointer_str": "example-value",
            "inner": {
                "value": "some-value"
            }
        }`
    testStruct := &Outer{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(testJson), testStruct)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", testStruct)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", *testStruct.PointerValue)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", testStruct.Inner)
}
```

Output:

```
&{ID:1 PointerValue:0x40c250 Inner:0x40c258}
example-value
&{Value:some-value}
```

Or

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Outer struct {
    ID           int          `json:"id"`
    PointerValue string      `json:"pointer_str"`
    Inner        Inner `json:"inner"`
}
type Inner struct {
    Value string `json:"value"`
}

func main() {
    testJson := `{
            "id": 1,
            "pointer_str": "example-value",
            "inner": {
                "value": "some-value"
            }
        }`
    testStruct := &Outer{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(testJson), testStruct)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", testStruct)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", testStruct.Inner)
}
```

Output:

```
&{ID:1 PointerValue:example-value Inner:{Value:some-value}}
{Value:some-value}
```

Updated: my meaning of efficiency was "efficient way to use memory"

Comment: This has _nothing_ to do with efficiency, it is about distinguishing whether a value is present or absent in the JSON.

Comment: @Volker thanks for your answer, I have got it. Leon explained it on duplicated question why it's not efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption that it is more efficient is wrong. The one without pointer is more efficient because there is no need for indirection and the value is in the memory cache along with the other values of `Outer`. Access will be faster.

Use a pointer when the Inner value is optional. It would have a `nil` value when the value is absent. Otherwise use the form without pointer. You would also use a pointer if the value of Inner in the JSON string may be `null`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, seems like it's duplicated question. But, your answer was good enough to understand it.